# run query in all schemas

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Hi I am a newbie to Oracle. I have a query that I need to run against all the schemas in database lets say (scott,hr,exampleetc) that has the table transaction in the database. 
    Can some one help what is the best way to do it ?? I have about 30 schemas in database I can't do it by running this against all schemas as it is time consuming..
    I was thinking a plsql will be the best way to do it but I am not enough knowledgeable to do this myself ..

```
query example:  
select sum(amount)
from abc.transaction t1
where t1.payment_method ='transfer' 
and TO_char(t1.result_time_stamp,'MONTH') = TO_char(sysdate,'MONTH')
order by t1.time_stamp asc;
```

Thanks is advance for help ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of queries you want to run, if they need to aggregate data from all tables at once or if you want to look through and run a command on each, but here's something that should get you started. It's a cursor that will find all tables named "transaction". If these are going to be ad-hoc queries, I would just copy the table name output from the below cursor, write a basic query and save it somewhere or make it into a procedure of some sort. Then just modify and re-use it in the future.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1
IS  
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
  WHERE upper(table_name) = 'TRANSACTION';
BEGIN
FOR c1rec in c1
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(c1rec.owner||'.'||c1rec.table_name);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Can I create an iteration where the output from this package can be passed in as input to the next query and get the output printed. example :  lets say that your output is scott.abc   .I want to use that output as next query like select col1,col2 from scott.abc;

Comment: You could. You might need to use dynamic SQL in order to do that, but it should still work for you.